# How to manually run proguard in android studio?

Tags: android, proguard

I need to run proguard on 2 dependent modules.
Each module need to generate seperate aar.
When I've tried using `minifyEnabled true` the first module build successfully but the build fail for the second module because some classes that I used are obfuscated.
I've defined `applymapping` flag in the second progurd config but it doesn't even get there because the build have failed.
Is there any way to run proguard only after all the modules have finished build process?
Is that can be automatically or have to be manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up by running it with commandline..

Comment: what is the command